# normal operator in Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $N$ be a normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Show that there exists a normal
operator $M$ on H such that $M^2 = N$.

My attempt:

Let $N∈B(H)$ normal operator then $N$ is self-adjoint and $σ(N)⊂[0,∞)$. If the function $f(t)=√t$ denotes the positive square root, then implies that $f∈C(σ(N)$. So there exists $M$ normal operator ($M∈C^∗(N)$ by construction) such that $M=f(N)$ . Hence $M^2=N$.

I want know if my answer is correct or if something is wrong.

Comment: Do you want $N$ to be positive?

Comment: There are plenty of normal operators that are not positive, for instance $-I$. Normal only means $T^*T = TT^*$.

Comment: There are normal operators that aren't positive, or self-adjoint.

Comment: I need help to solve this problem, please. Because my answer is not correct.