# Normal operators $N$ in Hilbert space $H$

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $N$ be a normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Show that there exists a normal operator $M$ on $H$ such that $M^2=N$.

How can I prove that. $N$ and $M$ are just normal operators.

My attempt:

Let $N∈B(H)$ normal operator then $N$ is self-adjoint and $σ(N)⊂[0,∞)$. If the function $f(t)=√t$ denotes the positive square root, then implies that $f∈C(σ(N)$. So there exists $M$ normal operator ($M∈C^∗(N)$ by construction) such that $M=f(N)$ . Hence $M^2=N$.

There is something wrong that $N$ does not positive. I do not have another idea. I need help to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [normal operator in Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343857/normal-operator-in-hilbert-space)

Comment: What do you mean "N does not positive" ?

Comment: I don't see where you assume positivity. As you say, the spectrum of $N$ is positive so $f \in C(\sigma(N))$ is well-defined. I don't have an answer.

Comment: Do you think my answer is correct? If not, would you like to point out the error in it, and give me the correct answer?